# Change Bibtex's details language

Tags: bibtex, french

I'm trying to change the information of bibtex from english to french like year->année and master's thesis -> Mémoire de mastère, I tried few things but they gave wrong translation, like master's thesis -> mémoire de maitrise !
Please how can I solve the issue

Comment: The details you wish to tweak are provided by the bibliography style that's in use. Which bib style do you employ? Please also provide more information than just "I tried [a] few things".

Comment: I set language to french and I used plain style for the bibliography

Comment: Well, file `plain.bst` is english as far as I know. Perhaps in the french Usergroup you can find someone who has already translated it to frensh? Otherwise use `biblatex` and `biber` ... Or you copy `plain.bst` to `frenchplain.bst` and translate there all english text to french text. Please see that the field names like `year=` or `@article` are defined fix, you can not translate them!

Comment: Sorry, but `year` is a reserved word, as it's the name of a field. BibTeX does not permit changing the names of fields (e.g., `author`, `year`, `publisher`, etc) or entry types (`@techreport`, `@unpublished`, etc).

Comment: The `plain` bib style is quite old, and almost everything in it is hard-coded, making modifications very tedious and error-prone. You would be better off loading the `natbib` package and using the `plainnat` bibliography style, which makes language customization far more straightforward.

Comment: Alright, thanks guys

Comment: Is the issue solved for you? How?